# Regular expression escaping in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a regular expression that works perfectly in Sublime text, or other text editors, and it does exactly what I need it to do.

Here is the regular expression

```
(?sm),"([\w\W]*?)Date completed:
```

The problem is, in PowerShell, it just doesn't do anything.

This is my little script

```
$text = Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv
$text -replace '(?sm),"([\w\W]*?)Date completed: ','REPLACED' | Out-File output.csv
```

If I replace the regular expression by plain text, it works great. So what is it that it does not like in my regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'plain text' ?

Comment: if I replace the regular expression by something like 'Example' it will find Example and replace it with REPLACED.

Comment: That comma and open double quote in here `'(?sm),"([\w\W]*?)Date completed: '` it is expecting a comma and double quote which I don't think exists in your source data that you are not including here. More impotantly you need to change you `$text`  to be a single string if you expect to use the single and multi mode. `$text = Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv | out-string`... im just doing to write and answer.

Comment: If a regex is not working we need source examples. Else it is impossible to know what is wrong. Show us how you made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info I got from the people who answered, here is how I was able to accomplish what I needed to do for the regular expression

```
$text = (Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv) | out-string

$regex = "(?sm),""\s.*?Date completed: "
$replace = ',"'
$output = [regex]::replace($text,$regex,$replace)

$output | Out-file c:\Tools\output.csv -Encoding ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you are trying to match against when you use single and multimode those are supposed to work on multi-lined strings. `Get-Content` by default will return a string *array*. `-replace` functions as an array operator and will run that pattern against each line individually.

So for starters make `$text` one string.

```
$text = Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv | Out-String
```

Or if you have at least PowerShell 3.0

```
$text = Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv -Raw
```